# hide sth and replace it with sth else when hovered

Tags: html, css

I want to replace sth with sth else at the same place when i've hovered anything.
esp i wanna do this with icons .
i would be glad if anyone help me.

```css
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.icon1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #170444;
}

.btn:hover+.icon1 {
  display: inline;
}

.btn:hover+.icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <p class="up">User Profile
    <i><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="icon">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
      </svg></i>
    <i><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="icon1">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4.5 15.75l7.5-7.5 7.5 7.5" />
      </svg></i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add code as codesnippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue here is with your CSS selectors. The `+.icon1` and `+.icon` selectors target the immediately subsequent sibling element. However, in your HTML structure, `.icon` is not an immediate sibling of `.btn`, so these selectors won't work as you expect.

Instead of using adjacent sibling selectors (`+`), you should be using descendant selectors to target the `.icon` and `.icon1` elements inside `.btn`.

Here's the corrected CSS:

```
.icon {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

.icon1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #170444;
}

.btn:hover .icon1 {
    display: inline;
}

.btn:hover .icon {
    display: none;
}
```

By using this CSS, when you hover over the `.btn` element, it will hide the `.icon` element and show the `.icon1` element.

Lastly, remember to remove the redundant semicolon in the `.icon` rule (`margin-top: 25px;;`).

Comment: thanks a lot dude, it worked exactly the way i wanted to